# Kotlin flow retryWhen function type mismatched

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-flow

I'm currently trying to fetch data from network call in my android app, updating the local database as soon as the network connection is up again.
To do this I'm using Kotlin Flow with the retryWhen function call to manage the error statement and retry after a certain period.
When I try to use the function I received the following error message

[image]

The getCharacters() is the following kotlin fuction the returns the result of a network call:

```
private fun getCharactes(): Flow<LoadCharacterResult> {
    var response: List<CharacterExternalDataModel>
    return flow<LoadCharacterResult> {
        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
            response = wizardNetwork.loadCharacters()
            if (response.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                emit(LoadCharacterResult.Failure(LoadCharacterError.NoInternet))
            } else {
                val characters = response.mapNotNull {
                    it.toDomain()
                }
                emit(LoadCharacterResult.Success(characters))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I looked for any possible example on how to use retrywhen correctly but I always have seen that the lambda uses these parameters (cause and attempt).
What this error refers to exactly ?

Comment: What happens if you name them x and y instead of cause and attempt? I wonder if that is a lint bug. Or try adding in your logic to return a Boolean and see if that causes it to scan it properly.